# Connect to MySql Database (Android)

Tags: android

I want to connect to a MySql DB but i don't find the code.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database).

Comment: That example does not connect to DB directly, but uses PHP script, which does the work and gives out JSON...

Comment: i found this before but this snippet use a php... I want to Accsess it directly.. Like in Java with the ODBC

Comment: You can't access it directly. The Android only supports SQLite locally :(

Answer (score 1):

Locally, the Android OS only supports SQLLite. To connect to a remote MySQL database, you'll need to use a webservice, either SOAP or REST.

Comment: The webservice should be run on the same server as the database. Use HttpClient in Android to query the database.